# Trying to use methods in basic circle program

Tags: java, methods

I'm really new to Java and I know I messed up bad somewhere on this program. Every time I try and fix it now, I make it worse. What I'm trying to do is create a basic program to calculate radius, diameter, and circumference of a circle. The code must include a method of printCircleInfo() for the output and must declare and use a no argument constructor to input data for the calculations. I'm totally off track with this I think, but this is what I've managed to do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle4
{
public static float PI; // PI.
public static float radius; // Radius of a circle
public static double dia;   // Diameter of the circle
public static double area; // Area of the circle

public Circle4() 
{
//Calculations
dia = radius*2; // Diameter calculation.
circ = PI*(radius*2);   //  Circumference calculation.
area = PI*(radius*radius);  //  Area calculation.
PI = 3.14159f;
Scanner in;
in = new Scanner(System.in);    // Input Scanner
System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle: "); //prompt for radius of the circle
radius = in.nextFloat();
}

public static void printCircleInfo()
{
    System.out.println("The diameter of the cicle is " + dia);  //  Output of Diameter.
    System.out.println("The circumferance of the circle is " + circ);   //  Output of Circumference.
    System.out.println("The area of the circle is " + area);    //  Output of Area.
}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
circle = circleData;
circleData = Circle4();
print = printCircle;
printCircle = printCircleInfo();
}
}
```

I have worked myself into such confusion that I don't even know where to begin to fix it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please at least specify where it goes wrong. What is is supposed to do, and what does it actually do? Precision is key.

Comment: A couple of quick notes: you can use Math.PI instead of declaring your own PI constant. The rest of your static members really shouldn't be static. I encourage you to read up on what static means.

Comment: I posted an insanely long answer before realizing that I was likely just doing homework for you. Instead, I'll say this: try to scale your code back so it's as simple as possible, and then add one thing at a time until it works. Don't go forward until everything that's come before is working the way you expect. I'm serious when I say you should likely start with a class that has only a `main()` method, and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues here:

(1)

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
circle = circleData;
circleData = Circle4();
print = printCircle;
printCircle = printCircleInfo();
}
```

In java you should declare what type each variable is of. You will get compilation error from this code

(2) 

You are declaring your fields [such as `radius`, `area`..] as `static`, and initialize them in constructor - I doubt that this is what you want. Note that `static` fields are shared among all instances of this class.

**There are more issues with this code. Try to compile it. Your compiler will tell you what's wrong [at least for compile time errors]. fix the mistakes, and re-compile.**